# View from SSAS Data Source View not shown under Cube partitions

Tags: sql-server, ssas, datasourceview

My problem is, that I created some SQL views in a database to create partitions in a cube.

For example:

- View1_Table1_Year2000
- View2_Table1_Year2001
- ...

Source for the Views is "Table1" filterd on different years.
I added the views to the DSV and added them to the cube partitions, which always worked.

Now there is the problem, that I recently created some views which were added to the DSV and are not shown under the partitons field of the table in the cube.

I already double checked everything, so if anybody has an idea that would be great.

Thaks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the views have the same columns like the source table/view of the measure group.